# REMMINA - White screen until I press CTRL+T - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: remmina

I have Remmina 0.9.99.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. When I choose a server from the list of connections, Remmina connects to the server but the entire screen is white. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd>, then the desktop shows but then I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd> again for the toolbar to go away. In Ubuntu 13.10, all I had to do was click off the Remmina window (or click on a different Remmina tab) to make it inactive, then click back and the desktop will load and it would be scaled to fit.

**"Remember last view mode for each connection" is checked** and the scale mode is set to HYPER. I have tried unchecking certain options and many different scenarios -- it's almost as if my preferences file is being ignored. A re-install does not fix it. Anyone else having this issue or know of a fix? I may just switch to NoMachine if I can't get this working, but Remmina has been so nice!

Thanks!

Comment: I just connected to a Windows 2012 server and the desktop showed up the first time, but it wasn't scaled to fit and the toolbar wasn't hidden. I have to click the "Toggle Scale Mode" and "Grab all keyboard events" buttons in the toolbar every time I connect -- not to mention another CTRL+T to hide the toolbar. It's as if the settings I make in the GUI have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest edition of Remmina fixes this issue (along with many others such as NUM lock not "following" you). Here are the three lines of code to upgrade to Remmina 1.2.0:

**sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next**

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp**

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug, reported here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1299290