# Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome, numeric keypad not working

Tags: gnome, 18.04, keyboard, numlock

Did the following as normal user and reboot, still not working

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state
```

Did the above as root got answer:

```
(process:3378): dconf-WARNING **: 14:35:23.197: failed to commit changes to dconf: Erreur lors de la génération de la ligne de commande « dbus-launch --autolaunch=0f76e53a9e0b4f1f8ddd7b2736e88499 --binary-syntax --close-stderr » : Le processus fils s’est terminé avec le code 1


gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state
'unknown'
```

Next ?
Purchase new keyboard still not working, funny the maths key  ∕⋅−+ works but not the numbers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Problem solved.

1. Click on triangle top right corner
2. Click on the icon wrench
3. Click in the left column on Universal Access
4. Go to the bottom of the page **deactivate mouse keys** (it is the first line in the box)
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

On a mac keyboard the "clear" key functions as the number lock key.

Answer (score 2):

Don't run this command as root/sudo ! Instead run it as user.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state
```

To turn on the numlock type

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state 'on'
```

Maybe [programatically setting numlock](https://askubuntu.com/a/703942/790920) will help you, based on numlock being reverted when switching keyboard layouts.

Comment: Thank you abu bua for your answer,
did tried it out priviously but it did not work

Comment: you should try another keyboard in the settings.

Comment: 1- Go to Adjustment
2-Go to Keyboard and mouse
3-Click on supplemtary options
4-In list click on numeric keypad disposition
5-I took the first UNICODE
Keypad is working normaly (sorry for translation my computer is in french)

Answer (score 0):

After looking around the Menu I found the answer as follows:

> Preference >accessibility > Mouse: "**Control the Pointer using keypad**" Turn it OFF!

**Ubuntu 18.04**:

> Srttings > universal Access > pointing and clicking: "**Mouse keys**" Turn it OFF!

Answer (score 0):

Choose appropriate keyboard

**Settings --> Region & Languages --> Input Sources --> Click add + --> Select your keyboard language --> Check if all the keys works**

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is because I should turn on the numeric keypad by pressing "Num Lock" key.

[reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/numeric-keypad.html.en)